# Why not , again Main Thread is calling .

Tags: java

I am reading `Thread` in `java` , i find a code_snippet in  book and tried to implement it , and it is not working as stated in the book , `why` ?

```
public class Main_thread 
{
    public static void main ( String args [] )
    {
        System.out.println("hello kakke");

        Thread t = new Thread () ;
        t.start();
    }   
}
```

why not , again "hello kakke" is printed .

Comment: I suggest you continue reading about threads. They have a decent concurrency guide [in the java docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/)

Comment: What do you expect to happen?

Comment: You should either copy the sample code from the book more carefully or throw the book away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> why not , again "hello kakke" is printed .

It is because you only print it once, at the beginning of your `main()` method.

The `Thread` which you create afterwards terminates immediately, and does not do anything additionally. In order to let the `Thread` perform some work, you need to override its `run()` method or pass an object to its constructor which implements the `Runnable` interface.

To get started with, try the following:

```
Thread t = new Thread () {
   @Override
   public void run() {
       for (int i = 0;   i < 5;  i++) {
           System.out.println("hello kakke - from separate Thread");
           Thread.sleep(500);
       }
   }
};
t.start();

for (int i = 0;   i < 5;  i++) {
    System.out.println("hello kakke - from main Thread");
    Thread.sleep(700);
}
```

Note: `Thread.sleep()` can throw an `InterruptedException` which you need to catch - I let that up to you as an exercise :)

Comment: if we use t.run() in place of t.start() , is it same !
because in my code ( i have not check yours ) run() method is called when i am using t.run() in place of t.start() .

Comment: No, it is not the same. When you call `run()`, you are synchronously executing the `run`-method of the `Thread` object, in the same way you are calling other methods from any object, in the **current thread**. Only by calling `start()`, a new Thread is created which executes its `run()`-method asynchronously and in parallel to other threads.

Comment: thanks ..... i found my mistake , i was treating thread.getName() as thread.isAlive() !